# Setup PhpStorm and Docker for PHP development without PHP on the host

Tags: php, intellij-idea, docker, phpstorm

I want to use PhpStorm (in fact IntelliJ with the PHP plugin) to develop my PHP software. I've been using a Linux laptop, with PHP 5.5 and the Oracle library. This has been very difficult to setup and I had a few compatibility problems.

I now have a MacBook where I need to setup the development environment. I want to try and use Docker for development, which should allow me to have different PHP versions with no interaction. But I still want to use PhpStorm, and if possible I don't want to install PHP on the host to keep it clean.

Is there a way to setup PhpStorm to use the PHP interpreter inside a docker machine so I don't need to install PHP on the host?

I'm using [this](http://mmenozzi.github.io/2016/01/22/php-web-development-with-docker/) as a guide and now I'm trying to follow [this](http://obrown.io/2015/12/23/phpunit-docker-phpstorm.html) to setup the php interpreter.

Comment: Official article: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Docker+Support+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm by itself does not **require** PHP installed anywhere.

PHP is required to run or debug scripts and tests, use composer, etc.

The simplest way for OSX host is to [use PHPStorm with vagrant](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+started+with+Vagrant+in+PhpStorm). You still can use it with docker as described in  [PHPStorm with remote interpreter](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Remote+PHP+Interpreters+in+PhpStorm), which still uses the same VM, but may require a bit more effort to configure Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

```html
php:
  build: php
  mem_limit: 7168m
  domainname: php.local
  hostname: php
  restart: always
  container_name: php
  ports:

    - "2222:22" # ssh
    - "8080:80" # http
    - "25:25" #SMTP

  volumes:
    - ~/opt/php:/opt/php/
```

Step's

1. Install Docker on your MAC
2. Use PHP docker image or create one according to your requirement.
3. Now create a docker-compose and use **volumes:** to mount your folder which contains's code into the docker
4. Now you can work with IDE and docker. Without installing PHP on MAC

REF:
https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/jenkins-docker-proxies-and-compose